# Ant exec: redirecting standard out but not standard error

Tags: ant

I have an `exec` task whose output I am putting into a property using the `outputproperty` attribute. The command may print some errors to stderr, I do not want the errors to be included in the output (since the output is being fed into another command) but rather to be printed out to the user. So I am redirecting the output and error into separate properties and `echo` the error property. It seems kind of a hack to have to `echo` the error. Is it possible to redirect the output of an exec but leave error on stderr or stdout? I assume it means setting the `error` attribute to some magical value but I cannot figure out what that value is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing `error` or `errorproperty` attributes and adding `logError="true"`.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html